# How to compare 2 Pages documents?

Tags: pages

I worked for a long time on a Pages document: `file.1.pages`.

I didn't activate `Edit > Track Changes`.

I saved the modified Pages with a new name: `file.2.pages`.

Now I would like to check I didn't forget a key point or made any error
and review all the modifications I made.

How may I compare `file.1.pages` and `file.2.pages`?

This isn't a comparison I can deal with manually (too much text, too many small spelling fixes).

I can't use any Microsoft software. I can use any Unix command line.

Comment: If you are only looking at the text (i.e., don't need to compare formatting changes as well), you could export both `.pages` files to plain text (File -> Export...) and then compare them with `diff`/Xcode's FileMerge/etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to proceed. The receipe isn't as simple as I thought.

1. From `Pages` export files to plain text:

   `File > Export > Plain Text...`

   so as to get 2 files: `file.1.txt`, `file.2.txt`.
2. Open both files with `vi` and apply the following command:

   `:%s,`<kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>`,`<kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>`,g`

   this command contains twice the sequence control+V, control+M which is the way to enter the raw return character. The strange effect of this command is to replace any return character (`0x0d`) with a standard newline character (`0x0a`) everywhere (`g` = global). Then the 2 files are now splitted in different lines and it becomes useful to compare them with any Unix text tool.
3. Change the 2 files encoding:

   `:set fileencoding=utf-8`

   so as to encode them as text files (and not binary files as they were exported from `Pages`).
4. Save the two files and quit `vi`:

   `:wq`
5. Run the standard `diff` command to compare the 2 text files:

   `diff file.1.txt file.2.txt`

Comment: Not ideal as you lose all kinds of formatting and footnotes when you turn it into plain text.